# How to use a variable that we defined outside the function inside the function

Tags: python, function

The job of this program is to take 20 numbers and at the end it prints the number that has more divisors. It prints with the number of divisors.

```
def big(gogo):
    sum = 0
    f = f+1
    for k in range(1, gogo + 1):
        if (gogo % k == 0 and f == 1):
            sum1 += 1
            big = gogo
        if (gogo % k == 0):
            sum += 1
    if (sum > sum1):
        sum1 = sum
        bigg = gogo
f=0
x = input("enter a number")
gogo = int(x)
big (gogo)
for i in range(1, 20):
    x = input("enter a number")
    gogo = int(x)
    big(gogo)
print(sum1, big)
```

my problem is:
i cant use f in my  function
and for each one i have this problem thats all{How to use a variable that we defined outside the function inside the function}
and the program says :local variable ' for examples sum1' referenced before assignment
i have this problems in each program when i use  function
please help me
thanks for all thing

Comment: Hi md-yz, Where is variable f initialized?

Comment: oh yes i edit it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Global keyword to use variables defined outside the function.

```
sum1=bigg=0
def big(gogo):
    sum = 0
    global sum1
    global bigg
    for k in range(1, gogo + 1):
        if (gogo % k == 0):
            sum += 1
            bigg = gogo
    if (sum > sum1):
        sum1 = sum
        bigg = gogo
for i in range(1, 21):
    x = input("enter a number")
    gogo = int(x)
    big(gogo)
print(sum1, bigg)
```

I believe the above code will handle your requirement.